# How to convert a webpage into a UIView with  UILabels for text

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, sdk, ios4

Is there a way to take text off a webpage, parse it and separate it into labels by the line it is on, on the webpage?

I'm right now converting the text to a UITextView then to a UILabel.

Comment: Where and how are you 'taking' text? Are you selecting & copy-pasting?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just read in the web page, scrape the lines or words you want, and put them into two custom `UILabel`s.

Comment: I don't know the code for it though....

Comment: I've explained what you need to look for, he's told you the general method. If you can't devise the rest yourself, stop programming and get into marketing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the HTML page for delimitations such as

```
<p/> 
<br>
```

and

```
<br>
```

and also the html5 new keywords such as

```
<article>
```

or

```
<section>
```

Comment: but what would i put into Xcode to read it

Comment: My company can write your code for you. 120$ per hour, estimation of required work 200 hours. Thank you, we look forward doing business with you again.

Comment: you'll definitely get business like that

Comment: It's called irony... in case you did not get it, I did not put any contact info :D